# Multi select list box asp mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

I'm working on an mvc .net web application and I'm using Entity Framework.
In my model, I have an entity called "utisateur" (user) and every user has one or more users that supervise him. What I want to do is generate a multi select list box that contains the list of all users inorder to select the new users' supervisors.

I tried to to that but i got this error :
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Here is my model class :

```
public class util 
{
    public util()
    {
        user = new utilisateur();
        listesups = Getutilisateurs(null);
    }
    public utilisateur user { get; set; }
    public int[] selectedusers;
    public MultiSelectList listesups { get; set; }       
    public MultiSelectList Getutilisateurs(int[] selectedValues)
    {
        var db = new BDGestionEntities();
        List<utilisateur> utilisateurs = db.utilisateurs.ToList();
        return new MultiSelectList(utilisateurs, "id", "login", selectedValues);
    }
}
```

And here is the part of the view that contains the list box :

```
 @Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.selectedusers, Model.listesups)
```

Here is the controller

```
    public ActionResult Create2()
    {
        return View();
    }

[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create2(util model)
    {
        utilisateur u = new utilisateur();
        if (model.selectedusers != null)
        {
            foreach (var selecteduse in model.selectedusers)
            {
                int selecteduseId = selecteduse;
                utilisateur utilisateur = db.utilisateurs.Where(c => c.id == selecteduseId).FirstOrDefault();
                u.superieur.Add(utilisateur);
            }


        }
        u.nom = model.user.nom;
        u.prenom = model.user.prenom;
        u.solde_conge = model.user.solde_conge;
        u.email = model.user.email;
        u.login = model.user.login;
        u.pwd = model.user.pwd;
        role role = new role();
        //role.nom_role = model.nom_role;

        role = db.roles.Where(c => c.nom_role == model.nom_role).FirstOrDefault();
        u.role = role;
        db.utilisateurs.AddObject(u);
        db.SaveChanges();
        ViewBag.id_role = new SelectList(db.roles, "id", "nom_role", model.user.id_role);
        return RedirectToAction("index");

    }
```

And here is the error message

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 
Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Source Error: 
Line 44:         <tr><td><label><b>Role : </b></label></td><td>@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.nom_role, values)</td></tr>
Line 45:         <tr>
Line 46:       <td><label><b>Liste des supérieurs : </b></label></td><td>@Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.selectedusers, Model.listesups)</td></tr>
Line 47:         </table>
Line 48:         <p>
```

Comment: Can you post your controller action which shows your view?

Comment: i edited the post and added the controller

Comment: Can you post the error, or at least what object the Object reference error is complaining about. Also it may help if you post the controller `HttpGet` action code for `Create2`.

Comment: done. hope someone could help. I think that the object reference error is complaining about `Model.listesups`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by editing my `Create2()` method like this :

```
public ActionResult Create2()
    {
        string login = User.Identity.Name;
        utilisateur ut = new utilisateur();
        var q = from j in db.utilisateurs where j.login == login select j;
        foreach (var i in q)
            ut = i;
        if ((ut.role.nom_role == "Stagiaire") || (ut.role.nom_role == "Developpeur"))
            return Redirect("~/Erreur");
        util u = new util();
        u.listesups = new MultiSelectList (db.utilisateurs, "id", "login");
        return View(u);
    }

[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create2(FormCollection collection, util model)
    {


        var sups = collection["selectedusers"];
        string login = User.Identity.Name;
        utilisateur u = new utilisateur();
        List<int> nums = new List<int>();
        var q = from j in db.utilisateurs where j.login == login select j;
        utilisateur courant = new utilisateur();
        try
        {
            foreach (var i in q)
            {
                courant = i;
            }
            foreach (var s in sups.Split(','))
            {
                nums.Add(int.Parse(s));
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Logger.Warning(ex.Message, "aucun superieur selectionné");
        }
        try
        {
            foreach (var selecteduse in nums)
            {
                utilisateur utilisateur = db.utilisateurs.Where(c => c.id == (int)selecteduse).FirstOrDefault();
                u.superieur.Add(utilisateur);
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Logger.Error(ex.Message, "Erreur ajout supérieurs");
        }
        //}
        if ((model.user.nom != null) && (model.user.prenom != null) && (model.user.login != null) && (model.user.email != null))
        {
            u.nom = model.user.nom;
            u.prenom = model.user.prenom;
            u.solde_conge = model.user.solde_conge;
            u.email = model.user.email;
            u.login = model.user.login;
            u.pwd = model.user.pwd;
            role role = new role();
            role = db.roles.Where(c => c.nom_role == model.nom_role).FirstOrDefault();
            u.role = role;
            try
            {
                db.utilisateurs.AddObject(u);
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Logger.Error(ex.Message, "");
            }

                ViewBag.id_role = new SelectList(db.roles, "id", "nom_role", model.user.id_role);
            return RedirectToAction("index");
        }
```